# Align Text In Bootstrap Well Beside FontAwesome Icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having difficulties aligning my headline and paragraph text in a "well". The "none" you see is a class to remove specific margins and is not relevant to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is my code

```
<div class="col-md-4 none">
    <div class="well none">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x fa-fw"></i>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <p>text goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it's doing and what I want it to do.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to make slight change in your html structure and wrap your text content inside the `div` and set its display as `inline-block`

```
<div class="col-md-4 none">
    <div class="well none">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x fa-fw"></i>
        <div class="text">
           <h3>Test</h3>
           <p>text goes here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css for that additional div is

```
.text {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wdo76bm1/)

Comment: Sachin, it aligned the text perfectly but moved everything down. http://i.imgur.com/IRMG8mO.png

Answer (score 1):

I would do this the following way. I like to use nested rows where ever possible to keep things clean.

```
/** CSS **/
.well h3 {
    margin-top:0px;
}
.fs48 {
    font-size:48px;
}

/** HTML **/
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class='well'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-xs-3 text-center'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user fs48'></span>
                </div>
                <div class='col-xs-9'>
                    <h3>Test</h3>
                    <p>text goes here</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See a working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6779/

You can simply replace the glyph with the font awesome class.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I tried this method and I'm having the same issue as stated below. It seems I'm having conflicting CSS somewhere.